# Load Flask config from multiple files

Tags: python, flask

I need to load configuration from multiple files.  I use the code below to load one file.  Should I use it repeatedly?  How do I load multiple configs?

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('yourapplication.default_settings')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can load config however you want, the only requirement is that it ends up in `app.config`.  `from_object` is just a helper method for if your config is in an importable Python file, such as the default settings in your example.  There are other helpers as well, or you can just treat `app.config` as a dict and set values however you want.

The standard method for overriding default settings is to load them and then load local settings from the instance folder.

```
app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
app.config.from_object('myapp.default_settings')
app.config.from_pyfile('local_settings.py', silent=True)
```

This will load `local_settings.py` in the instance folder into the config, and ignore if the file doesn't exist.

```
myproject/
    myapp/
        __init__.py
        default_settings.py
    instance/
        local_settings.py
```

Access the config wherever you need it by importing the app.

```
from myapp import app
my_value = app.config['my_key']
```